# How get plot from nlrq in R?

Tags: r, curve, nls, non-linear-regression, quantreg

Following workflow for nonlinear quantile regression seems to work. However I don´t know how to plot the resulting curve.

btw.: I´d prefer to use the function graphics::curve() instead of graphics::lines()

```
require(quantreg)

# load sample data
dat <- DNase
# introduce variable
x <- DNase$conc
y <- DNase$density
# introduce function 
f <- function(a, b, x) {(a*x/(b+x))}
# fit the model
fm0 <- nls(log(y) ~ log(f(a,b,x)), dat, start = c(a = 1, b = 1))
# fit a nonlinear least-square regression
fit <- nls(y ~ f(a,b,x), dat, start = coef(fm0))
# receive coeffientes
co <- coef(fit)
a=co[1]
b=co[2]
# plot
plot(y~x) 
# add curve
curve((a*x/(b+x)), add=T)

# then fit the median using nlrq
dat.nlrq <- nlrq(y ~ SSlogis(x, Asym, mid, scal), data=dat, tau=0.5)
# add curve
???
```

EDIT: What I´m looking for is a way to plot various quantile regressions of a formula, like a*x/(b+x).
Inserting the formula leads me to the question what to put as 'start' argument

```
dat.nlrq.075 <-  nlrq(formula=fit, data = dat, start=???, tau = 0.75)
```

Answer (score 2):

`curve` uses `lines` so there is really no reason to use `curve` when it's easier to use `lines`.

First ensure that data is sorted so plots come out right.  Then fit with `nls` or `nlrq` and use `fitted` for the fitted line.

```
library(quantreg)

dat <- DNase[order(DNase$conc), ]
fit.nlrq <-  nlrq(density ~ SSlogis(conc, Asym, mid, scal), data = dat, tau = 0.5)
plot(density ~ conc, dat)
lines(fitted(fit.nlrq) ~ conc, dat)
```

If you want to plot the fit at a different number of equally spaced points such as 250 then do the same except use `predict` instead of `fitted`:

```
x <- seq(min(dat$conc), max(dat$conc), length = 250)
lines(predict(fit.nlrq, list(conc = x)) ~ x, lty = 2, col = "red")
```

The same style works with `nls`.

Note that if you use `require` its value should be checked.  If you don't want to do that use `library` instead.

Comment: thanks for the advices! your code works fine for the example. Maybe it´s not clearly formulated by me that I´m looking for a way to integrate a formula, like (a*x/(b+x), into the nlrq(). I´d like to plot curves of various quantiles of the the formula (a*x/(b+x)